# editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath Scrolling problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am facing a very strange problem with editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method. I am planing to change the appearance of editable cells. It was working fine, but when i scroll the table i am not getting the table cell pointer in the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. So the new cells does not get the custom appearance.

I am using this -

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    // get tablviewcell pointer
    UITableViewCell* pCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // <- not getting the pointer when scrolling the table and new cells come up 

        //Changin cell appearance here ... 




}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the table view may call this method before it assigns a cell to the given index path. A more reliable way to customize table view cells would be to override -tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:. You can test the cell's editingStyle property there and act accordingly.

Comment: Hello Costique,
I just checked this and found that the methods execute in this order
1)- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
2) - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
3) -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

But i am not able to get the cell in the 3rd method itself. 

Please help!!

Comment: Strange. What does the table view send as the cell parameter (the second one) in -tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:? Is the method called at all? If not, check if the object implementing the method is actually the table view's delegate.